# How to access Magento user's session from outside Magento?

Tags: php, oop, session, magento, e-commerce

Im trying to access the Magento customer session in another part of my website.

```
domain.com/shop/ <- Magento
domain.com/test.php
```

The shop itself works like a charm, however im trying to determine within test.php if a customer is logged in, so I can display his name with a link to his cart.

Contents of **test.php** so far:

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/shop/app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
var_dump(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn());
?>
```

I keep getting **bool(false)** returned. I'm logged into Magento at domain.com/shop/ so ‘true’ is expected.

Am I forgetting something?

Comment: > "Exception: Warning: include(DoppelGangerView.php) ......" My guess would be it cannot find file DoppelGangerView.php somehow.. - Its not located in the current directory..
- Its not located within your include_path

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would recommend checking the path of the cookie that Magento sets. Most likely, it is set to `/shop`, so the cookie will not be accessible to your file above it.

You can modify the path that Magento uses to set its cookie in the control panel under `System -> Configuration -> Web (under the General heading) -> Session cookie management`

Comment: Why this is not working with joomla I tested it in separate page where it is working but not working with joomla always returns bool(false)

Comment: @Positive because this MAGENTO question is about MAGENTO, not joomla.

Comment: You may want to create your own session model class as part of a custom module. That way you can store on it whatever you need, then in the other part of your website, instantiate the mage::app object and pull your session model data.
Send me a message if you want more info on this

Answer (score 0):

it is under `confuguration-> web` on Magento ver. 1.10.1.1

Answer (score 0):

The same issue was driving me mad. I worked through the following until the last item solved it:

- Has the correct Mage store ID (current store) been set?
- Are you using the same session path as Magento?
- Are you using the same (sub)domain for cookie purposes?
- Are you using HTTP or HTTPS both inside and outside Magento?

If you've checked all the above, make sure you initialize a core "frontend" session on its own first like this:

```
// Initialise the core "frontend" session
Mage::getModel('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
```

Then you can access the customer/session like this:

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session", array('name' => 'frontend'))->getCustomer();
```