# Magento - Displaying total number of items in cart in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, magento

I have a Magento website as well as a Wordpress site and I'd like to be able to display the total number of items in the Magento cart, onto the header of the Wordpress site. In addition to the total number of items, I'm hoping to show the subtotal of the items in the cart as well.

Via Google I've found bridges between Wordpress and Magento, but a bridge seems like it'd be a complicated solution as I really only need these two pieces of data. I don't need users shared between the two sites, or anything else for that matter.

I've thought about doing it via sessions -- would that even work if the two URLs are different, and one is a subdomain of the other?

Any suggestions and input is much appreciated!

Comment: I found this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152613/magento-cart-session-data-outside-magento -- this author's code works when the file is inside of Magento's directory. Outside of that (in the Wordpress directory for example), it does not. I'll continue to look but any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at my answer here -> http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7112/what-is-the-best-strategy-to-integrate-wordpress-inside-of-magento . It uses a more involved example which pulls much more of Magento into Wordpress than you are looking for but it'll show you how to do it when WP is in its own directory.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to take a look at that now!